# How do I know that the data input on the socket has been ended?

Tags: python, sockets

I was doing some client server socket programming. I was delimiting messages by `<<msgBegin>>` and `<<msgEnd>>`. But I want to have another mechanism to detect end of the ill formed message not have `<<msgEnd>>` at all.

While doing `socket.recv()`, how do I know if the data input is ended? When there is no data, `socket` gets blocked. So I made [`socket.setblocking(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) and re ran, so now it immediately gives `BlockingIOError()`. Is it what I should catch in `try-except` block to signal myself end of data input on socket? or is their any other standard way to do the same?

Comment: When the peer closes its output half of the socket you will receive an EOF indication (a zero-length result) when you call socket.recv() in blocking mode.

Comment: "closes the output" means closes the connection, right? However the peer can just stop sending any more output /data without actually terminating the connection. How can I detect this?

Comment: Yes, I meant closing the connection. Detecting other kinds of network problems is a difficult problem. You can make an educated guess about how long to wait before declaring a problem, and then set a read timeout for that value.